# webDriver = null when exiting BeforeScenario block

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gherkin

I have a basic Gherkin / selenium framework. Which has a BeforeScenario and AfterScenario code block. The BeforeScenario code block works as expected but as soon as it exits, webDriver becomes null and therefor the code in AfterScenario does not run the .quit() code.

Steps:

```
using Coypu;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Steps
{
    [Binding]
    public class Steps
    {
        public IWebDriver webDriver;

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            // BeforeScenario code
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--incognito");
            options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL");
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            // BeforeScenario code
            if (webDriver == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Driver is null, call BeforeScenario() first.");
            }
            webDriver.Quit();
        }

        [Given(@"testOne")]
        public void GivenTestOne()
        {
            webDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text.Contains("text");
        }
    }
}
```

Feature:

```
Feature: Welcome-Page-Elements

Scenario: test
    Given testOne
```

Comment: driver becomes null before or after GivenTestOne()?

Comment: I seems to be after  `BeforeScenario()` and before `GivenTestOne()`

Comment: Try something for me (based on a hunch), and make the IWebDriver static. Do "public static IWebDriver webDriver;" and try again.

Comment: I tried that and it produced the same issue

Comment: Can you try removing the exception part? Maybe there is a thing going on with instances on gherkin that I don't know/understand. Remove the whole if and try again.

Also, if you don't have anything in AfterScenario (that closes the browser), does the browser stay open?

Comment: It looks like you're declaring an `IWebdriver` that is just scoped in `BeforeScenario` instead of setting the class level `webDriver`. Try changing this line: `IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);` to this: `webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);` Does that work? Or do you get a compiler warning?

Comment: @ThodorisKoskinopoulos Removing the exception part and the .quit causes the same issue.

Comment: @mrfreester thank that seems to have worked

Comment: @mrfreester sometimes what's right in front of you, is the easier to miss... or so I say to console myself :D
But I'm confused, shouldn't the compiler have an error when a local variable conflicts the global one? Having the same name?

Comment: @ThodorisKoskinopoulos I can't tell you how many times I've missed things like this. The compiler wouldn't give an error, but depending on what IDE and compiler warnings you have enabled you might get some kind of a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears you're creating a new variable `webDriver` that is only scoped to `BeforeScenario`.

The solution is to change this:

```
// declares a new method level webDriver
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

to this:

```
// uses class level webDriver
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```